# Outputting International Characters from MySQL to Java/Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, utf-8

Let's say someone uses this letter:  ë.  They input it in an EditText Box and it correctly is stored in the MySQL Database (via a php script).  But to grap that database field with that special character causes an output of "null" in Java/Android.

It appears my database is setup and storing correctly.  But retrieving is the issue. Do I have to fix this in the PHP side or handle it in Java/Android?  **EDIT**: *I don't believe this has anything to do with the PHP side anymore so I am more interested int he Java side.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds similar to: [android, UTF8 - How do I ensure UTF8 is used for a shared preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227763/android-utf8-how-do-i-ensure-utf8-is-used-for-a-shared-preference/14152728#14152728)

I suspect that the problem occurs over the web interface between the web service and the Android App. One side is sending UTF-16 or ISO 8859-1 characters, and the other is interpreting it as UTF-8 (or vice versa). Make sure:

- That the web request from Android is using UTF-8
- That the web service replies using UTF-8.

As in the other answer, use a HTTP debugging proxy to check that the characters being sent between the Android App and the web service are what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to extract your database access code to a standard Java Env then compile and test it. This will help you to isolate the problem.

Usually you won't get null even if there is encode problem. Check other problem and if other exception throws.

Definitely not problem of PHP if you sure the string is correctly inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a confusion between UTF-8 and UTF-16 or any other character set that you might be using for storing these international characters.  In UTF-16, the character ë will be stored as two bytes with the first byte beeing the null byte (0x00).  If this double byte is incorrectly transmitted back as, said, UTF-8, then the null byte will be seen as the end of string terminator; resulting in the output of a null value instead of the international character.

First, you need to be 100% sure that your international characters are stored correctly in the database.  Seeing the correct result in a php page on a web site is not a guaranty for that; as two wrongs can give you a right.  In the past, I have often seen incorrectly stored characters in a database that were still displayed correctly on a web page or some system.  This will looks OK until you need to access your database from another system and at this point; everything break loose because you cannot repeat the same kind of errors on the second system.

Comment: Well I can tell you, my MySQL database is storing the characters as `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: By casting your string field to a binary, you can verify each individual characters.  I don't have a copy of MySQL at hand at this moment but something like the following should work: Select Convert(varbinary(50), field1) from Test1;.  The second thing to do would be to try to store a foreign character directly from your Android application and see how it is stored on the backend database.  This way, you should know if the problem comes from the Android side or the PHP side.