# Rails- RSPEC incomplete multibyte character error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, fabrication-gem

I am using Rails 3.2.13 with ruby 1.9.3. I keep getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: @user = Fabricate :user, role_ids: [role.id]
PG::Error:
   incomplete multibyte character
 # ./spec/controllers/api_controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The frustrating thing about the error is that it occurs intermittently. Sometimes I can run the tests 10 times without it happening and then other times it happens every time.

The code around line 6 of the projects_controller_spec.rb file where the error occurs looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::ProjectsController do
  before do
    role = Fabricate :data_collector_role
    @user = Fabricate :user, role_ids: [role.id] # this is line 6
    @project = Fabricate.build(:project, proposal: Fabricate(:full_proposal))
    @project.save(validate: false)
    @permission = Fabricate :permission, user: @user, project: @project
    @project2 = Fabricate.build(:project, proposal: Fabricate(:full_proposal))
    @project2.save(validate: false)
    request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'
    request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] =   ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(@user.api_key)
  end
```

The Fabricator that gets called on line 6 above looks like this:

```
Fabricator :user do
    username { sequence(:username) { |n| "foo#{n}" } }
    password 'foobar'
    password_confirmation 'foobar'
    email_address "user@example.com"
    home_phone "123456789"
    work_phone "456789189"
    sales_channel
end
```

The same code gets called in other specs that aren't for the API controllers and they work 100% of the time.

Every now and again RSPEC crashes completely and gives the following error:

```
     Failure/Error: get :show, { id: @project.id }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
/Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:182:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:182:in `dump_failure_info'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:175:in `dump_failure'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:19:in `block in dump_failures'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:17:in `each'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:17:in `each_with_index'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb:17:in `dump_failures'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:98:in `block in notify'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:97:in `each'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:97:in `notify'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:81:in `finish'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:36:in `report'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
from /Users/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167468/rails-3-how-to-handle-pg-error-incomplete-multibyte-character

Comment: @PriteshJ There are no non UTF-8 characters anywhere in the tests that could be causing the problem. Thanks for pointing that out though

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your file spec/controllers/api_controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb

```
# !/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: Updated the answer, try again.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately

Comment: Put that header in all your .rb files involved in that test's execution. Trust me, its that.

Comment: # ./spec/controllers/api_controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' This means that the required file that you are adding in line 6 needs that header.

Comment: I added the lines above to every .rb file in the project and the error is still occuring

Comment: Maybe you truly have a multi-byte character somewhere, then you need to convert it to UTF-8. Try doing this to your .rb files: http://superuser.com/questions/16672/how-can-i-convert-multiple-files-to-utf-8-encoding-using-nix-command-line-tools

Comment: I don't think that is the case either. The script in the link didn't chance any of the files. I also ran "file --mime" over all of my .rb files and they came back as being ASCII or UTF-8, which should be fine since ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.